# Debugging Python AWS CDK application in VSCode

Tags: python, aws-cdk, vscode-debugger

I have a AWS CDK application written in python. I want to debug this in VSCode. I do understand this would not be the normal convention. Since in my case cdk is installed globally and the cdk.json directs the global cdk to run my `"app": "python3 app.py"..` and at runtime cdk is using jsii to probably transpile python cdk into javascript to then convert to AWS Cloudformation.

With all that complexity stated, I should either be able to run the python debugger with correctly providing `import aws_cdk as cdk... app = cdk.App()` with the context. I can start the python debugger and pick up my venv/ with aws_cdk installed no problems, but it has no context. I cannot find any documentation on providing the context. using `cdk.app(context={'key':'value})` returns `app.node.get_all_context() = {}`. I was then thinking I could start cdk and use VSCode to attach to the running process. I cannot run `<global path>/node cdk syth` since `cdk` is itself an executable and is supposed to be run `cdk syth` directly (I am on a MAC). One obvious  additional test would be to run `npm init` and add cdk locally. That would help me use existing documentation on stackoverflow. Although that may work for me that is not desirable since I would have a npm setup for debugging plus a python setup for the app.

Python was chosen as the cdk language because there is more python experience than typescript in this app development. Although as I am reading it seems that python is a second rate language for aws cdk development.

Comment: AWS documention have always been dodgy, can't say I've tried what you're trying to describe but have you tried this yet ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/get_context_var.html